# Error when running program with VirtualShellTools from a service

Tags: delphi, windows-services

I create a service in Delphi. I need this service to run my program. In Windows 7, I use this code to execute a program :

```
procedure ExecuteProcessAsLoggedOnUser(FileName: string);

implementation

function GetShellProcessName: string;
var
  Reg: TRegistry;
begin
  Reg := TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ);
  try
    Reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    Reg.OpenKeyReadOnly
      ('Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\WinLogon');
    Result := Reg.ReadString('Shell');
  finally
    Reg.Free;
  end;
end;

function GetShellProcessPid(const Name: string): Longword;
var
  Snapshot: THandle;
  Process: TProcessEntry32;
  B: Boolean;
begin
  Result := 0;
  Snapshot := CreateToolHelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
  if Snapshot <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
    try
      FillChar(Process, SizeOf(Process), 0);
      Process.dwSize := SizeOf(Process);
      B := Process32First(Snapshot, Process);
      while B do
      begin
        if CompareText(Process.szExeFile, Name) = 0 then
        begin
          Result := Process.th32ProcessID;
          Break;
        end;
        B := Process32Next(Snapshot, Process);
      end;
    finally
      CloseHandle(Snapshot);
    end;
end;

function GetShellHandle: THandle;
var
  Pid: Longword;
begin
  Pid := GetShellProcessPid(GetShellProcessName);
  Result := OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, Pid);
end;

procedure ExecuteProcessAsLoggedOnUser(FileName: string);
var
  ph: THandle;
  hToken, nToken: THandle;
  ProcInfo: TProcessInformation;
  StartInfo: TStartupInfo;
begin
  ph := GetShellHandle;
  if ph > 0 then
  begin
    if OpenProcessToken(ph, TOKEN_DUPLICATE or TOKEN_QUERY, hToken) then
    begin
      if DuplicateTokenEx(hToken, TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY or TOKEN_DUPLICATE or
        TOKEN_QUERY, nil, SecurityImpersonation, TokenPrimary, nToken) then
      begin
        if ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(nToken) then
        begin
          // Initialize then STARTUPINFO structure
          FillChar(StartInfo, SizeOf(TStartupInfo), 0);
          StartInfo.cb := SizeOf(TStartupInfo);
          // Specify that the process runs in the interactive desktop
          StartInfo.lpDesktop := PChar('WinSta0\Default');

          // Launch the process in the client's logon session
          CreateProcessAsUser(nToken, nil, PChar(FileName), nil, nil, False,
            CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE or NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, nil, nil, StartInfo,
            ProcInfo);

          // End impersonation of client
          RevertToSelf();
        end;
        CloseHandle(nToken);
      end;
      CloseHandle(hToken);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

The code works fine for an "empty" program. So I drop TVirtualExpolorerTreeview onto the form of my program. if I start my service then there will be an error when the program is being called. I guess the program can't enumerate PIDL or blabla (I don't know much about Windows Shell). How do I force the program so it can run normally?

Comment: does this need to be a service? Would a scheduled task be more suitable?

Comment: @David, I make a small security program that need elevation, auto startup and it require background tasks for monitoring some objects. In my mind, I need to create a service and a GUI. Unfortunately, the service can't call the GUI :(

Comment: The service can't call the GUI, but only because the GUI isn't a function and therefore can't be *called* by anything. (Remember that "the" GUI might be a misnomer. There might be nobody logged in. Or there might be several people logged in at once.) There are many ways for services to communicate with non-services, including mailslots, sockets, named pipes, events, and shared memory. But the service needn't *start* the GUI. Leave that to user's session (such as by using the Startup group).

Comment: @Rob : I mean GUI is refer to a program. For example the service found something and communicate with the program then program will do the rest action. The problem is if the program is not running, the service can't call the program.

Comment: Oh I don't. I just analyzed similar program,  if I terminate the program, it won't be started again by the service. Thx,

Comment: OK. So what? If the GUI program isn't running, then there's no user to see it happen anyway (or the user doesn't want to see it anymore), so why do it at all? If it's something that *needs* to happen, then the service should perform the task itself instead of trying to give it to one of the GUI programs.

Comment: If the GUI program is not running then there's no user to see it happen anyway. You can imagine an antivirus software. If I terminate the GUI program then I execute a virus, the service/protection won't show its GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `WinSta0` might be the cause:

Starting with Windows Vista, the way that services (and processes started by services) can interact with the desktop changed, as services no longer run in the same session as the user at the console.

By default, they cannot interact with the desktop any more.

See [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/windowscompatibility/thread/e6fee5e2-5e2f-401b-a9ee-5abf9c284bcc) for some nice links on this matter.

Comment: Well, I am confuse right now because I just tried to run my service in XP and Oh no I also got an error in VST's unit (I use madExcept).

Comment: yeah, WinSta0 is categorically not the interactive desktop as your code says!

Comment: Ok, I got a nice link from @Jeroen and I should not call my program from the service. Bad design. Sorry I am still learning. Thx.

Comment: Actually it's not unheard of for services to start GUI processes. It can be done.

Comment: Yes it can be done. The fact is the code above can run a program in XP and 7 but not for some programs. But I'm sure my program design was bad. But if somebody can run a program with VST unit from a service, it would be nice to know it.

Comment: What error code does `CreateProcessAsUser()` actually return when it fails?  I doubt this problem is related to VST specifically.  Also, rather than hunting for the user's Shell app (BTW, the Shell Registry key can have multiple executables listed), you should consider using the WTS API instead, such as `WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId()` and `WTSQueryUseToken()`.  You should also call `CreateEnvironmentBlock()` before calling `CreateProcessAsUser()` as well, to make sure the app has the correct user-specific environment.

Comment: Thanks Remy, I can't touch my code right now, but I found your code in https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=34956&start=0&tstart=0 . I'll give it try.